# Add a box around the selected tab bar item

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4

I would like to do something in the vein of having a box appear or a circle around the tab bar item that the user has selected other than just changing the color. Is this even possible and if so how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming that you are using UITabbar, you can always have images for tab bar, where you can set an image for normal state and selected state.. In your case, your selected state image can have a circled/boxed image.
Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to achieve this. I will list down 3 of them below.

**1)** You can set `selectionIndicatorImage` like this in `AppDelegate`,

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UITabBar.appearance().selectionIndicatorImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "boxImage")
    return true
}
```

For the rest of 2 you have to create a subclass of `UITabBarController` like below and set this class in the `storyboard` for the `tabBarController`

```
class MyTabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

}
```

**2)**  In this method you have to ask your designer to create the selected images with box. Set the unselected/normal and selected images like below in `viewDidAppear` and you are done.

[image]

**3)** Add an imageView in tabBar like below. In `storyboard`, you can assign `tag` for each `tabBar` item so that in the `didSelect item` callback, we will consider the tag as index of the selected item. Lets consider you have 5 tabBar items and you assigned tags from 0 to 4. Now you will just get the tag and update the position as shown below

```
class MyTabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

    // MARK: - Properties
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "boxImage"))

    // MARK: View's Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tabBar.addSubview(imageView)
    }

    /// Tabbar item selection callback
    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        updateImagePosition(at: item.tag + 1)
    }

    private func updateImagePosition(at index: Int) {
        guard let count = tabBar.items?.count else { return }

        let eachItemWidth = view.bounds.width/CGFloat(count)

        let selectedItemX = (eachItemWidth * CGFloat(index)) - eachItemWidth/2 - imageView.frame.width/2
        let selectedItemY = tabBar.bounds.height/2 - imageView.frame.height/2

        imageView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: selectedItemX, y: selectedItemY)
    }
}
```